# Visual Studio can't detect my Clang compiler installation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clang, visual-studio-2019

I'm using the latest VS 2019 16.2, which is supposed to have Clang with MSBuild support as well Clang w/ CMake of course.

I installed the CMake components as well as the Clang-cl for v142 build tools (But not the Clang Compiler component that comes with VS!) because I already have Clang compiler v8.0.0 installed in the default path in my system.

I want to use Clang (either through MSBuild or CMake) but both approaches failed.
VS simply doesn't seem to detect my compiler (although the version is supported, supposedly).

Is there a way I can manually make it detect it? May add a path in some options or reinstall clang?
I don't want to install the VS one for my specific reasons.

[image]

[image]

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/VC/Tools/Llvm/8.0.0/bin/clang-cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/HP/Source/Repos/CMakeProject1/out/build/x64-Clang-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_8f083 
    [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_8f083.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_8f083.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_8f083.exe 
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_8f083.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1422~1.279\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_8f083.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_8f083.exe /implib:cmTC_8f083.lib /pdb:cmTC_8f083.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /foCMakeFiles\cmTC_8f083.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_8f083.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specified
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.        C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake  60
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/) about supporting Clang in Visual Studio? There they talk about setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm just trying to set them but I don't know how,

Comment: Well, the first thing you can try/check: whether the compiler's directory is in your PATH. And please, provide **exact error message** for your problem (better, provide full configuration log until that message). Description "VS simply doesn't seem to detec my compiler" is too vague.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I already checked in the PATH var, I have the bin directory of the clang installation just alright, I will update the post with a screenshot.

Comment: It is a wrong way to set a compiler as non-cached variable before `project()` call. BTW, on your screenshot there is `CMakeSettings.json` tab (near the `CMakeLists.txt` tab). Exactly this tab is active on the screenshot [in the blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/) about setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variable. Why do not use approach suggested in the official blog?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi, again. Yes I downloaded the whole Clang workload, the variables are all set but I still can't compile, I get just one error, I attached a new image.  BTW I tried to compile clang with an MSBuild project but it won't either, it says it misses the Win10 SDK. Why is that? could it be that I need Win10 SDK to compile on CMake as well.

Comment: Please, past error log into the question post as a **text**, not as *image* containing the text. There are many issues when use image instead of text. E.g. your screenshot trims long lines.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  Sorry, I attached a file.

Comment: The error message is "The system cannot find the file specified" and it concern about `rc` executable. Here is a bugreport with very similar simptoms: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18745. Check that variable `CMAKE_RC_COMPILER` is set in the cache. If it is, then it is a [bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17804) and it is fixed in CMake 3.14. In that version you may also face with this [bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18957). It is fixed in clang 8.0 or, possibly, in some newer CMake version.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The `CMAKE_RC_COMPILER` is set to the value of "rc" in the json settings file. Also when trying to generate the cache I get the above error again. I'll post the while log files.